# Riverpod: notifier vs state - difference?

Tags: riverpod

I am unable to find the difference between:

```
ref.read(moveFieldNotifierProvider.notifier).state = something;
```

and

```
ref.read(moveFieldNotifierProvider.state).state = something;
```

Answer (score 0):

`notifier` is a property of `StateNotifierProvider` that gives you access to the `StateNotifier`.

`state` is a property of `StateProvider` that gives you access to the `StateController`.

Since `StateNotifier` and `StateController` both have a property called `state`, which is the data currently stored in the provider.

Comment: so where would I use which one, or are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `StateProvider` for simple types, for example, if it's just a `String`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, and you have a simple logic to modify it.

For example, if you have an on/off switch and need to control its value from other widgets, you can use `StateProvider<bool>`.

In a chat application, you can use StateProvider with Family modifier to have an unread messages state:

```
final unreadCounterProvider = StateProvider.family<int, int>((ref, channelId) {
  return 0;
});
```

If you need something more complex, like a List or Map in state, it's better to use `StateNotifier`, and if you have Riverpod 2.0+, there is an updated version: `NotifierProvider`

Here is an example of Counter using NotifierProvider:

```
final counterProvider = NotifierProvider<CounterModel, int>(CounterModel.new);

class CounterModel extends Notifier<int> {   
  int _delta = 0; 
  int? _cachedState;

  @override
  int build() {
    ref.onDispose(() => print('CounterModel.onDispose'));
    _delta = ref.watch(dependencyProvider);
    print('CounterModel.build _delta: $_delta, _cachedState: $_cachedState ');
    return _cachedState ?? 0;
  }

  void increment() {
    state += _delta;
    _cachedState = state;
  }
}
```